# Wordpress plugin adding firstname and lastname on registration

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

So i'm making a extension plugin FOR another plugin. What i want to achieve is that i upon registration they are required to add their Firstname and Lastname, so i added the fields for it, i did the errorchecks for it and everything worked when testing.

But when adding the last step the actual updating the database when i click the register button i get critical errors, the user is added to the database, but no first or lastname. I assume i don't even get in the "function registration_save_user".

Could someone help me on assisting me with my final hurdle, keep in mind i'm very new at all this so any improvements are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

```
add_filter( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'FootballPoolRegisterNames', 'init_extension' ) );

class FootballPoolRegisterNames {
    public static function init_extension() {
        add_action( 'register_form', [__CLASS__, 'registration_form_extra_names'], null, 2 );
        add_filter( 'registration_errors', [__CLASS__, 'registration_check_fields'], null, 3 );
        add_action( 'user_register', [__CLASS__, 'registration_save_user'], null, 4 );
    }
    
    //1. Add fields. Just the basic layout added before the dropdown.
    public static function registration_form_extra_names() {
        $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';?>
        <p>
            <label for="first_name">Voornaam</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(  $first_name  ); ?>" size="25" autocomplete="voornaam" required="required">
        </p>
        <?php
        $last_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';?>
        <p>
            <label for="last_name">Achternaam</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(  $last_name  ); ?>" size="25" autocomplete="achternaam" required="required">
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    //2. Check fields 
    private static function check_field( &$errors, $field, $message ) {
        if ( Football_Pool_Utils::post_string( $field ) === '' ) {
            $errors->add( "{$field}_error", "<strong>Fout:</strong> voer je {$message} in." );
        }
    }

    public static function registration_check_fields( $errors ) {
        // Check the added fields
        self::check_field( $errors, 'first_name', 'voornaam' );
        self::check_field( $errors, 'last_name', 'achternaam' );

        return $errors;
    }
    
    //3. Save userdata
    public static function registration_save_user( $user_id , $first_name, $last_name) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] )) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $first_name );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $last_name );
        }
    }
}
```

have tried multiple times, but all of them where without first and lastname and had a critical error, but all of them posted to my database, so i assume the

```
add_action( 'user_register', [__CLASS__, 'registration_save_user'], null, 4 );
```

and/or

```
public static function registration_save_user( $user_id , $first_name, $last_name) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] )) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $first_name );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $last_name );
        }
    }
```

Is completly wrong.

Comment: “But when adding the last step…i get critical errors” - what errors do you get?

Comment: Hello, i solved my issue, well to be honest ChatGPT solved my issue. I fed it the code that worked (everything up until saving the userdata) and let it finish my class with the correct prompt lol. I will post the answer in a more detailed post.

Answer (score 0):

So as mentioned in the comments i let ChatGPT read my file and fix the code that was faulty (the saving to the database) and it corrected my code and told me what i did wrong.

I made a big error in the add_action part on line 7, **when trying to define 'user_register' it only expects 1 variable** which is the $user_id i had "*NULL, 4*" because i didn't know any better and i'm bad.

Then it spit out the following function which worked perfectly with the code i already provided without the $first_name and $last_name i previously tried to append.

```
//3. Save userdata
public static function registration_save_user( $user_id ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) && !empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
        }
        
        if ( isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) && !empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['last_name'] ) );
        }
    }
```

So everything works now thanks to ChatGPT lol!
Thanks to all.